# #C #string #array How to program this project with C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am a freshman(CSIE) from Taiwan.

It is my first post,if my expression is not perfect enough,

thanks for your consideration.

**example input:**

**25 is 5 5 book 100**

**output:**

**135**

**below is my code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
    char a[100] = { 0 };
    int s[10] = { 0 };
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    gets_s(a);

    while (a[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (a[i] >= '0' && a[i] <= '9')
        {
            s[j] = s[j] * 10 + a[i] - '0';
            i++;
        }
        else if (a[i] < '0' && a[i]>'9') { i++; j++;}

        else 
            i++; j++;
    }
    for (j = 0; j <= strlen(a); j++)
    {
        s[j] = s[j] + s[j + 1];
    }
    printf("%d",s[j]);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But when I input my example input,the output is '0'.

How should I edit my code?

I would like to use array to store sum.

At last,Thanks all that answer my question.

Comment: Hashtags are not needed in the title.

Comment: You only print one element, `s[j]`.

Comment: Is not `char *gets_s(char *s, rsize_t n);` need 2 arguments rather than `gets_s(a);`?

Comment: `else 
            i++; j++;` is like `else {
            i++; } j++;`

Comment: what is the code trying to accomplish?

Comment: regarding: `gets_s(a);`  it would be good programming to let the user know what is expected of them rather than leaving the user with a blinking cursor and no indication of what they should do next

Comment: regarding: `gets_s(a);`   Strongly suggest using `fgets()` as that is portable.

Comment: regarding: `else if (a[i] < '0' && a[i]>'9') { i++; j++;}`   `a[i]` cannot be both < '0' AND > '9'  Suggest: `else if (a[i] < '0' || a[i]>'9') { i++; j++;}

Comment: regarding: `for (j = 0; j <= strlen(a); j++)
    {
        s[j] = s[j] + s[j + 1];`  this (can be) accessing beyond the end of  array s[], resulting in undefined behavior

Comment: after correcting several problems, as listed in the prior comments, the contents of `s[]` are: `25 0 0 5 10 5 0 0 0 0`  I don't see anything in `s[]` that looks like `135`

Comment: regarding the statements: `#include<stdlib.h>` and `#include<ctype.h>`  Nothing in the posted code is using anything from those two header files.  It is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.